# Exiftool command in Bash for-loop not working

Tags: bash, shell, exiftool

I'm trying to write and overwrite jpg metadata with exiftool in a bash for-loop, but a specific command won't work in the loop. I want to overwrite the gpstimestamp with the datetimeoriginal data, this works if executed on the commandline, but not in the script..

```
for f in $(ls *.jpg); do

    [... stuff that works]

    exiftool "-gpstimestamp<datetimeoriginal" $f
done
```

Any ideas why this isn't working in the loop?

Comment: (1) Never parse the output of `ls` this way, [Parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is the *very first* entry on the big list of [bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). And (2) quote your variables. And if you want help, it's always better to tell us HOW something is failing. "This doesn't work" isn't enough - include any error messages, or show the erroneous behaviour, and describe what you were expecting, and how you detect the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop can be done in a simpler way:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.jpg
do

    [... stuff that works]

    exiftool "-gpstimestamp<datetimeoriginal" $f
done
```

> Note: You instead of running a for loop, you can execute `exiftool` to
>   process all `*.jpg` files in the directory using:
>
> [exiftool info](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/mistakes.html)

```
exiftool "-gpstimestamp<datetimeoriginal" -ext jpg .
```

[exiftool man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/exiftool)

> -ext EXT    (-extension)         Process files with specified extension

Comment: Thanks for the tips! But the "-gpstimestamp<datetimeoriginal" command isn't working... It works when I use it like this: exiftool "-gpstimestamp<datetimeoriginal" file.jpg

Comment: It works! Mea culpa, I tried it on jpeg files, not jpg... facepalm!!!! :D

Answer (score 2):

Exiftool does not need to be run in a loop and will run much quicker without (Exiftool [common mistake 3](https://exiftool.org/mistakes.html#M3)).

Use this command directly after your loop
`exiftool '-gpstimestamp<datetimeoriginal' -ext jpg /path/to/target/dir`

This will copy `DateTimeOriginal` to `GPSTimestamp` for all Jpg files in the target directory.  You can add `-r` to recurse into subdirectories.

One thing you need to take into account is the fact that `GPSTimestamp` is expected to be UTC time and `DateTimeOriginal` usually is the timezone the image was taken in.